# Layout issue about alignment

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a button help with a margin right and left of 10dp. Then I add a button test to the left of a `TextView` (centered horizontal), below the button `help` and align left to the button `help`.

The problem is that the button test is not exactly aligned to the button `help` like `TextView` `test1` to the right of button `help`.

What am I doing wrong?

[image]

Here is my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/mid"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/help"
        android:text="Help"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/test"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/help"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:background="#87CEFF"
        android:text="Test"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@id/mid"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@id/help"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/test1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/mid"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@id/test"
        android:layout_alignTop="@id/test"
        android:layout_alignRight="@id/help"
        android:text="test1\ntest2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textColor="#0000ff"
        android:background="#00cc00"
        />    

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: So what you want.
what is your expectations to display the view

Comment: if you look the output of the layout, the button test is not exactly aligned (by some pixels) to the button help. Neither the textview test1 to the right of help.

Comment: your light is aligned just give any background color  to yout Help Button

Answer (score 1):

i think thats just the background of the help-button.
if you use a custom background for it aswell, it will fill up all his space.

Answer (score 0):

wrap test button and textview in a relative layout and align parent right and left each one.

Comment: too cumbersome. the background solution is better from my point of view. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong in your code only one thing you have to add to your button test is **android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"** or any colour of your choice, android by default provides padding padding to button.

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/help"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
    android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"
    android:text="Help" />
```

i have made necessary changes in above code try it hope it solves your issue